# Interview Microphone for Sony Handycam HDR-CX500E

Tags: microphone

We're recording interviews in a reasonably quiet room using a Sony HDR-CX500E. While the picture quality is acceptable, the audio quality isn't. We're using Sony's own shotgun microphone, but it's picking up a lot of background noise, and the voices sound thin.

Unfortunately, this camera doesn't have a 3.5mm microphone jack, only Sony's proprietary shoe (Advanced Interface Shoe, or AIS). As far as I can tell, only Sony makes microphones for this, and it only makes small shotgun-like microphones.

What options should I look at? Did I miss a good microphone that works with AIS and the HDR-CX500E? Or is it my best option to record audio separately, maybe with a USB microphone, and synchronize it with the video afterwards?

Comment: Perhaps there's an XLR to AIS adapter available somewhere so you could connect more common mics?

Comment: I've found some sites explaining how to take apart an AIS microphone and turn it into a microphone jack, and I've found one adapter that's no longer available, but no actual currently-for-sale product. I'll keep looking, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a proper audio input, I'd go with a separate audio recorder. Tons of options... it all comes down to budget. If you get one with usable built in mics, you could place it close to the talent for recording. Best bet is a mic run into the recorder though.